# Remove dot and parentheses from the URL in rewrite rule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the a rewrite rule where I am trying to remove any dots and parentheses from the URL and I managed to get get to the point where I can do one or the other but just can't seem to combine both. How would I write the rule so that if any url has a dot or parentheses, they get removed? Thanks.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [\(\)\.]+
RewriteRule ^(.*)[\(]+([^\)]*)[\)]+(.*)$ /$1$2$3 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)[().](.*)$ /$1$2 [E=DOT:Y,DPI]
RewriteCond %{ENV:DOT} Y
RewriteRule ^([^().]+)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

This uses an environment variable as a way to know when to redirect. Any number of parentheses and dots will get removed and when they're all done, the URL gets redirected.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Tried it locally but it is redirecting it to index.php when I put it within the custom rewrite rules section of the [Joomla .htaccess file](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/htaccess.txt#L46).

Also tried checking for apache error logs (on /var/logs/apache2/error.log) but can't see anything there.

Comment: @NirajPandey You need to put it before **any** routing rules that you have. Otherwise, it'll redirect to where you're internally routing.

Comment: While it didn't solved my issue as I probably should have asked it in a different way, the answer is correct (as it removes dot and parentheses).